# increase the number of map and reduce function

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I have a question.
I want to increase my map and reduce functions to the number of my input data. when I execute `System.out.println(conf.getNumReduceTasks())` and `System.out.println(conf.getNumMapTasks())` it shows me:

```
1  1
```

and when I execute `conf.setNumReduceTasks(1000000)` and `conf.setNumMapTasks(1000000)` and again execute the `println` method it shows me:

```
1000000  1000000
```

but I think there is no change in my mapreduce program execution time. my input is from cassandra, actually it is the cassandra column family rows that is about 362000 rows.
I want to set the number of my map and reduce function to the number of input rows..

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the number of map/reduce tasks for your map/reduce job does define how many map/reduce processes will be used to process your job. Consider if you really need so many java processes.

That said, the number of map tasks is mostly determined automatically; setting the number of map tasks is only a hint that can increase the number of maps that were determined by Hadoop.

For reduce tasks, the default is 1 and the practical limit is around 1,000.

See: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

It's also important to understand that each node of your cluster also has a maximum number of map/reduce tasks that can execute concurrently. This is set by the following configuration settings:

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
and
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum

The default for both of these is 2.

So increasing the number of map/reduce tasks will be limited to the number of tasks that can run simultaneously per node. This may be one reason you aren't seeing a change in execution time for your job.

See: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred-default.html

The summary is: 
Let Hadoop determine the number of maps, unless you want more map tasks.

Use the mapred.tasktracker..tasks.maximum settings to control how many tasks can run at one time.

The max value for number of reduce tasks should be somewhere between 1 or 2 * (mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum * #nodes). You also have to take into account how many map/reduce jobs you expect to run at once, so that a single job doesn't consume all the available reduce slots.

A value of 1,000,000 is almost certainly too high for either setting; it's not practical to run that many java processes. I expect that such high values are simply being ignored.

After setting the mapred.tasktracker..tasks.maximum to the number of tasks your nodes are able to run simultaneously, then try increasing your job's map/reduce tasks incrementally.

You can see the actual number of tasks used by your job in the job.xml file to verify your settings.